# Data From "GET" and "MySQL PDO"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is my code i **try** to do this "**condition**" : 
**if** data from "**get**" **==** data in "**mysql pdo**" then echo alert "this data is **exist** in database"
**else** "insert data to mysql pdo",
when ever i use this code ( down code ) , i can use that for **just** **one** "**row**" 
for **example** we have : 
1 [row] - "***123456***"
2 [row] - "**123**"
if i try to add "**123**" i got **error** , **but** i "**can**" add **again** "***123456***" after we have
1 [row] - "**123456**"
2 [row] - "123"
3 [row] - "**123456**"
and do like that ( **odd / even** ) !!!

> $GetAu = $_GET["au"]; // Data from get
>
> $sql = $db->query("SELECT * from trans"); // Sql Cond
>
> while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
>
> $DbAu = $row["au"]; // All of data in "au" table
>
> }
>
> if($DbAu != $GetAu){
>
> $sql = "INSERT INTO trans (au) VALUES ('$GetAu')";
>
> $db->query($sql);
>
> echo "Added true";
>
> }else{
>
> echo "This data is exist!";
>
> }

And sorry for my poor english thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$exist = false;
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row["au"] == $GetAu) {
        $exist = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$exist) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO trans (au) VALUES ('$GetAu')";
    $db->query($sql);
    echo "Added true";
} else {
    echo "This data is exist!";
}
```

Comment: i test that , it was do that again ( Add and Add and Add ... ) :(( thanks again

Comment: hah thanks for your idea , i really like that dear Thanks :* i use this : 
 if($row["au"] == $GetAu){
   $exist = true;
   exit;
 }
And the problem solved , thanks :*